# my List lost its values when leave page_load() in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a public list like this:

```
public List<links> googleRec = new List<links>();

public class links
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int place { get; set; }
}
```

I set these values in page_load()

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {  //googlerec get its values in page_load correctly}
 }
```

when I want to use values in googlerec outside page_load , It has 0 records

```
foreach (links element in googleRec)
        {

            //googlerec has no record here
     }
```

Comment: Have you considered using `viewstate`?

Answer (score 2):

You can store List in session

```
Session["googleRec"] = new List<links>();
```

Comment: How should I retrieve its fields?

Comment: List<links> googleRec = (List<links>)Session["googleRec"];

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewState` which is usually used save information specific to particular web page.

To save your list in `ViewState` in your `Page_Load()` event

```
ViewState["myList"] = googleRec;
```

To get the list back from `ViewState`

```
List<links> googleRec= (List<links>)ViewState["myList"];
```

Here is a detailed link if you want to know more about `ViewState`.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: I should declare  myList like this? `public List<links> myList= new List<links>();` because now I have this error :`The name 'myList' does not exist in the current `

Comment: I think you got it wrong. Declare the variable as you were doing before `public List<links> googleRec = new List<links>();` and then assign it to `ViewState["myList"] = googleRec; ` note that "myList" is just a key name you change it to whatever you want. this "myList" key is just used to set and get the data from `ViewState`

Comment: I receive this error :`Type '_Default+links' in Assembly 'App_Web_r3cgi21i, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.` I can't store an object in viewstate unless it's marked as serializable.How I solve it?

Comment: add `[Serializable]` attribute over your class.

`[Serializable]
public class links
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int place { get; set; }
}` this should fix the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

Code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{

    public List<links> googleRec = new List<links>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            googleRec = GetLinks();
            Session["links"] = googleRec;
        }
        else
        {
            googleRec = (List<links>)Session["links"];
        }
    }

    private List<links> GetLinks()
    {
        return new List<links>
        {
            new links {description = "new link 1", place = 1, title = "link title 1", url = "https://www.facebook.com/" },
            new links {description = "new link 2", place = 2, title = "link title 2", url = "http://www.google.pl" },
            new links {description = "new link 3", place = 3, title = "link title 3", url = "https://twitter.com/?lang=pl" },
        };
    }
}
```

View:

```
<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

        <% foreach (links item in googleRec) { %>

        <div>
            <%= item.title  %>
        </div>

        <% } %>
    </div>
</div>

<hr />

<asp:Button ID="sender" runat="server" Text="Do postback" />
```